# Postman unable sending to OWASP ZAP with the same proxy configuration

Tags: security, postman, owasp

[image: POSTMAN PROXY CONFIGURATION]

[image: OWASP ZAP PROXY CONFIGURATION]

I'm trying to do vulnerability scanning API. but when I send the Postman with post method, it don't get detect by OWASP ZAP or don't get send to OWASP ZAP.

I try to use IP 127.0.0.1 but OWASP ZAP don't allow it. Are there any tips to solve the issue?

Comment: Zap is a HTTP proxy, so you have to configure Postman to use Zap as proxy by using 127.0.0.1 as proxy host and the  configured Zap proxy port as proxy port.

Comment: @Robert when i try to configure by using 127.0.0.1 on OWASP ZAP, it said "Failed to save the options: Unable to listen on this address and port: 127.0.0.1:8080".

Comment: Please read my comment again. I wrote that you should configure Postman to use ZAP as proxy. In ZAP you simply have to check which proxy port is configured.

Comment: Is something else listenning on 8080? Thats usually the only reason ZAP will not be able to use it.

Comment: @SimonBennetts im using it as my home server and tunneling using 8080 port with cloudflare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something else is using port 8080 then ZAP wont be able to use it. Just choose a different port for ZAP, e.g. 8090.